# How to set variable in to Ms Sql select

Tags: sql-server, variables, select

How can I set in MS Sql select variables, idea looks like this:

```
Declare @var int

SET @var = 0;

Select (if(idid = @var) then sum+1 else sum-1) AS Sum,
   set @var = id 
FROM table
```

Edit based on comments.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
ID  INT PRIMARY KEY,
IDID INT,
SUMM INT 
)

INSERT INTO @T
SELECT 1,1,4 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,5 UNION ALL 
SELECT 3,2,6 UNION ALL 
SELECT 4,2,7 UNION ALL 
SELECT 5,3,8
```

In select result I need:

```
ID  IDID  SUMM 
--  ----  ----
1   1     4 
2   1     0 
3   2     6 
4   2     0 
5   3     8
```

Comment: What you posted doesn't make any sense.  What's the schema and purpose?

Comment: I've edited your question based on your comment and still have no idea what you are asking. Can you please edit the question yourself and explain the rules used to get the expected result. Do you want only the row with the minimum `id` value for each `IDID` to contain its stored value and all other rows for that `IDID` to show a `summ` of zero?

Answer (score 24):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
Declare @var int, @id int
SET @var = 0

SELECT @id = id FROM Table t

if(@id = @var)
BEGIN
    SET @var = @var + 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @var = @var - 1
END

print @var
```

Comment: Table structur:

    ID   IDID   SUMM
    1    1       4
    2    1       5
    3    2       6
    4    2       7
    5    3       8



In select result I need:

    ID   IDID   SUMM
    1    1       4
    2    1       0
    3    2       6
    4    2       0
    5    3       8

Answer (score 7):

Just use SELECT.

e.g.

```
SELECT @myValue = MyField FROM MyTable WHERE ....
```

Comment: It looks from his sample code like he is trying to do a loop of some sort, though.

Comment: @valisimo - Please provide your table structure and example data to explain your requirement rather than snippets of invalid SQL.

Answer (score 5):

Although, like others, I don't really get the idea, the query below produces the output as specified in the original post (which, in turn, has been derived from your comment). *This requires **SQL Server 2005** or higher*.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    ID,
    IDID,
    SUMM,
    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IDID ORDER BY ID)
  FROM @T
)
SELECT
  ID,
  IDID,
  SUMM = CASE RowNum WHEN 1 THEN SUMM ELSE 0 END
FROM cte
```

Basically, the `SUMM` output column contains `SUMM` from the original table if this is the first occurrence of `IDID` as ordered by `ID`, otherwise the column contains `0`.

Not sure how far it is from what you are after, but maybe it'll help you to explain your problem more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the bad habit of violating referential integrity while using my test data. But this was useful for restoring the data with referential integrity after I was finished testing my scripts:

```
DECLARE @foreign_id INTEGER;
   SET @foreign_id = (SELECT TOP 1 (FK_column) FROM (FK_table));
-- To confirm the value is what you want it to be
SELECT @foreign_id;
```

Now I could multi-insert the data back once I was finished, using this value to ensure that:

```
-- Referential integrity check:
SELECT (FK_column) FROM (FK_table)
   WHERE (FK_column) NOT IN
   (SELECT (PK_column) FROM (PK_table));
```

did not return any values.