# Instantiating temp table based on the result of joins after creating a new variable

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to store the result of a query as a temp table in SQL Server. Can someone explain why the `set` syntax is wrong here? I thought I followed for format [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152001/how-to-set-variable-in-to-ms-sql-select) correctly.

```
select * 
into #temp_Academic 
set XlistGrp_Course_CRN = s.Subject+' '+s.Course_Number+' ('+x.XlistGrp_Course_CRN+')'
from AcademicYear r 
inner join Xlist x on r.XlistGrp = x.xlistgrp and r.term=x.term
inner join Sections s on x.term = s.Term and x.XlistGrp_Course_CRN = s.CRN
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: what is that `set`? it is not a correct syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That set is for assigning the variable, and I assume you have a typo, missing `,` in your post. and generally speaking you should not have both select, set in one selecting clause.

What you are looking for is just alias the column, you can try:

```
select *,XlistGrp_Course_CRN = s.Subject+' '+s.Course_Number+'   ('+x.XlistGrp_Course_CRN+')' 
 into #temp_Academic,      
from AcademicYear r 
inner join Xlist x on r.XlistGrp = x.xlistgrp and r.term=x.term
inner join Sections s on x.term = s.Term and x.XlistGrp_Course_CRN = s.CRN
```

OR

```
select *,s.Subject+' '+s.Course_Number+' ('+x.XlistGrp_Course_CRN+')' as XlistGrp_Course_CRN 
into #temp_Academic, 
from AcademicYear r 
inner join Xlist x on r.XlistGrp = x.xlistgrp and r.term=x.term
inner join Sections s on x.term = s.Term and x.XlistGrp_Course_CRN = s.CRN
```

For your reference post, the op's question is how to assign the result from a query to one variable instead giving value directly.

Compare:

```
SELECT @varble = value FROM TABLE -- assume only one value returned
```

VS

```
SET @varable = 5 --assume you declared @varable as INT
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @CListGrp as nvarchar(255)

select *, @XlistGrp_Course_CRN = s.Subject+' '+s.Course_Number+' ('+x.XlistGrp_Course_CRN+')' into #temp_Academic 

from AcademicYear r 
inner join Xlist x on r.XlistGrp = x.xlistgrp and r.term=x.term
inner join Sections s on x.term = s.Term and x.XlistGrp_Course_CRN = s.CRN
```